# Format sqlite table to custom display in C# Datagrid

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagrid

I have a Sqlite database whit a table like below, but I wan to display in a datagrid using windows forms in c#

```
Warehouse   Product Amount
=========   ======= ======
1           p1       1  
1           p2       2
1           p3       3
2           p1       4  
2           p2       5
2           p3       6
3           p1       7  
3           p2       8
3           p3       9
```

I want to display  like this

```
Warehouse   p1  p2  p3...
=========   ==  ==  ==
1           1   2   3
2           4   5   6
3           7   8   9
```

I used this code to fill the datagrid like the one example

```
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    var sql = "select Warehouse, Product,Amount  from existencias_dump";

    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, db.m_dbConnection);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    var table = dataSet.Tables[0];

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

I want to display like the second but don't know were are recomended changes in the sqlite query or in the final dataset in both cases I don't know exactly how to proced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query and the result set are ok. The problem is that what you need (called cross tabular or pivot view) is not natively supported by the `DataGridView` component (and many others). Luckily what you are asking for is still doable in many ways, including (but not limited to) manually creating grid columns and rows and populating them with data, or converting the data table in the expected format with something like this

```
static DataTable ToCrossTab(DataTable source, string rowField, string columnField, string valueField)
{
    var rowSource = source.Columns[rowField];
    var columnSource = source.Columns[columnField];
    var valueSource = source.Columns[valueField];
    var table = new DataTable();
    // Columns
    table.Columns.Add(rowSource.ColumnName, rowSource.DataType);
    foreach (var columnName in source.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr[columnSource].ToString()).Distinct().OrderBy(name => name))
        table.Columns.Add(columnName, valueSource.DataType);
    // Rows
    foreach (var group in source.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(dr => dr[rowSource]).OrderBy(g => g.Key))
    {
        var row = table.Rows.Add(group.Key);
        foreach (var dr in group)
            row[dr[columnSource].ToString()] = dr[valueSource];
    }
    return table;
}
```

and changing your last line to

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ToCrossTab(table, "Warehouse", "Product", "Amount");
```